# Columns:2 makes odd numbers list more at right side

Tags: css, html-lists, margin

I need to divide list into two. For that I need to use `Columns:2` CSS.

Everything works fine but when I give `margin` to `li`, the divided list gets more number at right side (when there is odd number list).

I need to have more numbers at left side in case of odd-number-list

Please assist me with this issue.

```css
ul.uptime {
 columns: 2;
 width: 70%;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
ul.uptime li{
 margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="uptime">
<li>Mar 2020: 509ms</li>
<li>Feb 2020: 517ms</li>
<li>Jan 2020: 285ms</li>
<li>Dec 2019: 439ms</li>
<li>Nov 2019: 285ms</li>
<li>Oct 2019: 299ms</li>
<li>Sep 2019: 321ms</li>
<li>Aug 2019: 581ms</li>
<li>Aug 2018: 378ms</li>
<li>Jul 2018: 327ms</li>
<li>Jun 2018: 352ms</li>
<li>May 2018: 366ms</li>
<li>Apr 2018: 269ms</li>
<li>Mar 2018: 235ms</li>
<li>Feb 2018: 268ms</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Mozilla Firefox developer